# Catching NSNotification in Phonegap Plugin

Tags: javascript, xcode, cordova, ios6, phonegap-plugins

I'm creating a phonegap plugin. Now on my .m file I'm listening to NSNotification which if triggered will go to the specified function or method. My question is, is there a way for my javascript side to listen if a certain event from my .m class was triggered? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this objective c code in your .m file:

```
[super writeJavascript:@"console.log('!!!!! logging stuff !!!!!');"];
```